# Redis connection drops on Azure

Tags: azure, docker, redis, node-redis

My redis instance is running in a docker container on Azure VM. I connect to same instance from my Local app as well as my Azure App. Both have exact same code base but after some idle time on both environments if I try to run my Azure App it becomes unresponsive. If I check redis log it shows only 2 clients(1 of it is cli itself). So I see that my redis connection from Azure is ended but in my Azure App log there is no connection end logged. I am using node_redis to connect to redis from APP. I am using retry strategy as following which is given as example on node_redis.

```
retry_strategy: function (options) {
    if (options.error && options.error.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
        // End reconnecting on a specific error and flush all commands with
        // a individual error
        return new Error('The server refused the connection');
    }
    if (options.total_retry_time > 1000 * 60 * 60) {
        // End reconnecting after a specific timeout and flush all commands
        // with a individual error
        return new Error('Retry time exhausted');
    }
    if (options.attempt > 10) {
        // End reconnecting with built in error
        return undefined;
    }
    // reconnect after
    return Math.min(options.attempt * 100, 3000);
}
```

Am I missing any Azure side configuration needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution and I hope no one else gets stuck in such a situation.
With help of following link I was able to determine the problem.
https://serverfault.com/questions/661704/azure-closing-idle-network-connections

Solution:
Set your tcp_keepalive in redis.conf to less than 240
Commands to using redis-cli:

```
CONFIG SET tcp_keepalive 200
```

and check settings with

```
CONFIG GET tcp_keepalive
```

Since Azure server does not exactly close the connection but only changes mapping of connection our client doesn't get end event or triggers retry_strategy.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked like a charm!